# What is the difference between list1 and list1[:] in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to implement a backtracking solution to a Leetcode problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/) and found out an unexpected bug in my code. In the first solution I do out_list.append(curr_array) in line 8 and it outputs me an empty output list.

```
class Solution:

    def subsets(self, nums):

        def backtrack(curr_array, curr_idx):

            if len(curr_array) > 0:
                out_list.append(curr_array)

            for idx in range(curr_idx, len(nums)):
                curr_array.append(nums[idx])
                backtrack(curr_array, idx + 1)
                curr_array.pop()

        out_list = []

        backtrack([], 0)

        return out_list
```

Whereas when I do out_list.append(curr_array[:]), I get the correct answer as output.

```
class Solution:

    def subsets(self, nums):

        def backtrack(curr_array, curr_idx):

            if len(curr_array) > 0:
                out_list.append(curr_array[:])

            for idx in range(curr_idx, len(nums)):
                curr_array.append(nums[idx])
                backtrack(curr_array, idx + 1)
                curr_array.pop()

        out_list = []

        backtrack([], 0)

        return out_list
```

I've been under the impression that list1[:] is the same thing as list1. Can you tell me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cur_array` is a reference to the original list. When you append `cur_array` to `out_list` and then later modify `cur_array`, `out_list` changes as well.

`cur_array[:]` is a copy of `cur_array` (same as `cur_array.copy()`). When you append `cur_array[:]` to `out_list` and then later modify `cur_array`, `out_list` does not change because it has its own copy of `cur_array`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you make a misunderstand on list.

```
>>> a = [] # Here we announce a list
>>> id(a)
82700416
>>> id(a[:])
82700544
```

As you can see, slice will make a copy of list.